# Google Script - Auto add recently uploaded YT videos from subscriptions to specific playlists

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api

I am having a little trouble with a google script which I found on github.
Original Code: https://github.com/Elijas/auto-youtube-subscription-playlist-2

**What this script does:**

You add the channel ID which you have subscribed to on youtube to a google spreadsheet and reference them to the Playlist ID you want new videos to be added:

[Spreadsheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJdQl.png)

**What my issue(s) are:**

The script itself works perfectly fine as long as I open up the spreadsheet and execute the "updatePlaylists" function manually.

But as soon as I add a time driven trigger (or try to execute the function in the script editor) the script keeps failing:

[TypeError: Cannot call method "toString" of undefined.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDT5D.png)

But I found a "fix" for that specific error on the internet. So I changed this specific code line to:

```
if (typeof sheet === 'undefined') sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MY_GOOGLE_SHEET_ID').getSheets
```

But now I get the following error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot find function getDataRange in object [object Object]. (Row 18, File "Code")"
```

Which would be this part of the code:

[Cannot find function getDataRange in object [object Object]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHG1F.png)

As the script seems to work, as long as I execute it from within the spreadsheet, I guess it must have something to do with the 'Sheet' Variable within the script. But as I am not really familiar with google's scripting language I really hope someone here can help me out on this problem.

Any idea would be highly appreciated :)

EDIT: as requested by Chris I will post the part of the code here. I just didn't want to paste the whole script as it is huge. I hope this is enough. If not you can download the whole script as it is right now from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wyzuraOK8O4AY74ioK0m5AhSCKftJu6bLa8BEt1Kawk).

```
function updatePlaylists(sheet) {
  if (typeof sheet === 'undefined') sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Jj1Sx0mvfCKfYFcfX4karP9ztPgkyURj3pBvOExsljQ').getSheets()[0]; // Hotfix, Paste the Sheet ID here, it's the long string in the Sheet URL
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var reservedTableRows = 3; // Start of the range of the PlaylistID+ChannelID data
  var reservedTableColumns = 2; // Start of the range of the ChannelID data
  var reservedTimestampCell = "F1";
  //if (!sheet.getRange(reservedTimestampCell).getValue()) sheet.getRange(reservedTimestampCell).setValue(ISODateString(new Date()));
  if (!sheet.getRange(reservedTimestampCell).getValue()) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setHours(date.getHours() - 24); // Subscriptions added starting with the last day
    var isodate = date.toISOString();
    sheet.getRange(reservedTimestampCell).setValue(isodate);
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the code instead of pictures of the code? It's easier to help fix things If we can copy and paste.

Comment: The line that you changed was not part of the original functionality - it's added by an another contributor and might've broken things (?). You can try to compare it to original code here before the merge, e.g. https://github.com/Elijas/auto-youtube-subscription-playlist-2/blob/a53d0ea033d9a9aaf5e8832edfcffc10777701b3/sheetScript.gs since this code worked well when I tried to run "updatePlaylists" function manually (I'm the original creator of the google script).

Comment: Ok thx, I will test it tonight and will give feedback here. And thank you so much for your hard work. This script is really awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the reply of Prometheus, the original creator of the script, I was finally able to solve the problem.
Apparently the "updatePlaylists" function has been edited by a contributor on github.

**Everyone who stumbles over the same problem, do this:**

Simply replace the "updatePlalists" function in Code.gs with the original version:

```
function updatePlaylists() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var reservedTableRows = 3; // Start of the range of the PlaylistID+ChannelID data
  var reservedTableColumns = 2; // Start of the range of the ChannelID data
  var reservedTimestampCell = "F1";
  //if (!sheet.getRange(reservedTimestampCell).getValue()) sheet.getRange(reservedTimestampCell).setValue(ISODateString(new Date()));
  if (!sheet.getRange(reservedTimestampCell).getValue()) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setHours(date.getHours() - 24); // Subscriptions added starting with the last day
    var isodate = date.toISOString();
    sheet.getRange(reservedTimestampCell).setValue(isodate);
  }
```

Comment: Glad it works again! Mentioned your solution in the official README for everyone else.